# Azure APIM foward custom header and change backend URI

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-api-management

I am a newbie with azure APIM. I am trying to implement such a functionality where I need to make sure that when the client sends the request with the proper subscription-key and wants to add a custom header to route to the appropriate backend service URL. Without adding a Web Service URL only API URL Suffix I have.
Otherwise, I have to create 10 same apis with little changes in the URL.

The client adds the custom header in his request to base URL https://my-app-api.azure-api.net/api/customers

Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: Keys-for-auth 
"X-subjectName": my-subject-value

When the request came to the backend to override the URI with that header, I need to extract the custom header from the call and override the backend URI. Can I do it via policies?

After overriding my backend URI it should look like this:
https://my.api.com/api/v1/my-subject-value /customers

Thank you!

---

Policy from the comments:

```xml
<inbound> 
     <set-variable name="myvar" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("my-header",""))" /> 
     <set-backend-service base-url="my-api-backend.com{{myvar}}" />    
</inbound>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Tried with set variable and custom-header and after this to set the backend address but I receive 500, take a look:
```
<inbound>
        <set-variable name="myvar" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("my-header",""))" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://my-api-backend.com/{{myvar}}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get the value of the variable this way:
`context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("myvar")`

With the [rewrite-uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rewrite-uri-policy) the value of the variable can be appended to URL:

```xml
<inbound> 
     <set-variable name="myvar" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("my-header",""))" /> 
     <set-backend-service base-url="my-api-backend.com" />    
     <rewrite-uri template="@("/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("myvar"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />        
</inbound>
```

Please find below a complete working example for demonstration:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="myvar" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("my-header",""))" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/?name=" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("myvar"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://api.agify.io" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Request with custom header:

[image]

Result from trace:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution, but I don't know why it doesn't work. I think the rewritten URL is masking the original request endpoint
let me give you more context.
When I request https://my-apim.azure.net/get-my-endpoint

Policy gets the header that I send in the request. 
rewrite-uri template= /api/v1/my-header-value/get and should add the /get-my-endpoint/ from the reqeust right?
but seems it doesn't combine base-url with rewrite only i guess.

Comment: I figured myself and with a lot of help from you. Added one more variable 
 <set-variable name="completePath" value="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Trim('/').Substring(context.Api.Path.Trim('/').Length))" />
To get the original API path and added in URI-rewrite-template. Thanks!